# Error: import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg') (Tensorflow Jupyter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, jupyter

I was trying to run tensorflow object detection. I got this error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/erdogan/PycharmProjects/CNN/tens/model/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.py
/Users/erdogan/PycharmProjects/CNN/tens/model/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py:25: UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

The backend was *originally* set to 'MacOSX' by the following code:
  File "/Users/erdogan/PycharmProjects/CNN/tens/model/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 71, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    line for line in traceback.format_stack()


  import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
```

How can I solve this? It still works but I do not want to hide this error as the other topics suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my obtect_detection_tutorial Notebook and the solution I found was:

CUTTING the following code line:

```
    %matplotlib inline
```

And pasting it before the last for loop that iterates over the test images (last cell of code).

Hope it helps.